# Windows equivalent of nautilus? (Double pane explorer)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

On Linux you've got Nautilus which allows you to hit F3 and bring up another pane, somewhat like the old Norton Commander.

Is there any application (preferably Open Source) that acts like that for Windows? So far my searches have been in vain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free alternative to Total Commander](http://superuser.com/questions/38951/free-alternative-to-total-commander)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Total Commander**](http://www.ghisler.com/) and [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com):

[image: (screenshot)] [image: (screenshot)]

Total Commander is closed-source and shareware (which is a bit unfortunate, because it is awesome).

Far Manager used to be shareware, but version 2.0 seems to be open-source.

Comment: There are free alternatives to Total Commander: http://superuser.com/questions/38951/free-alternative-to-total-commander